# Visual Studio 2017 User-defined Custom Syntax Color

Tags: visual-studio, theming

What I'm trying to implement is a color change in comments that are followed by a specific "code tag", say `// notetoself:`.

So instead of the regular default green for comments, or completely changing the color for comments, I only want comments starting with `// notetoself:` to change color to something like this:

[image]

Pretty aesthetic, isn't it? But I digress.

I tried messing with the `.vstheme` but I'm not aware of how the tags are defined outside the `.vstheme` itself, as in where Visual Studio defines them.
I also tried looking for a way to only customize **Task List Tokens** but they're considered mere comments by the theme editor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a VS2017 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarRwemi.BetterComments) that can do *exactly* what you want.